# sort results by the distance from a location javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

i have a table e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE places (id UNIQUE, name, latitude, longitude)
```

i then loop through my dataset and calculate the distance between users location and my rows, then i display as a list in HTML.

My problem is that i dont know how to sort this list out by ascending order of distance.

Do i save the distance back into the Places table and then do another Select * with an Ascending order...?

can i not do something like select my results, but order them by running a javascript function. basically something like this:

```
tx.executeSql('select * from places order by ' 
function getdistance(userLat, UserLong, places.latitude, places.longitude)
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you calling a function that you want in Javascript, you cannot use a function defined external to the database engine as a comparison operator, especially if used via the syntax you provide, where it is being evaluated externally from the query - you need the data to find the value to evaluate the order that the data should be returned. There is no way for the data to get anywhere!

Instead, you could create a table that has an extra, empty column, and then calculate it via Javascript on the client side, in the HTML. This would allow multiple users to use the application, and you can sort it there.

OF course, if you are comfortable with doing so, you can create or define a C function in SQLite - I am unfamiliar with the process, but it is described in their documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).  This would allow you to call it in the SQL itself; `Select *, Distance(UserLat, UserLong, places.latitude, places.longitude) as dist from places, uservalues order by dist`

Alternatively, as suggested, you could save the data back into the database, but this will limit concurrency.

Lastly, you could use MySQL or another database system that is more fully featured.

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer... I dont think i can create a C function. So im stuck with what i suggested. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the tools just are not what is needed for the job. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have provided an implementation of the [Haversine Distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) that you can use to calculate a near approximation of the distance between two Longitude / Latitude pairs. The returned distance can be in any unit of distance, so long as you know the radius of Earth in said unit.  For this example I have provided Earth's radius in both Kilometers and Miles.

Be mindful to pass arrays with Longitude at index 0 and Latitude at index 1, since this function was written to work with GSON style location data.

You will have to do your SQL query first, then calculate the distance after the results are available from your query.

```
var earth_radius = {
  kilometers: 6371,
  miles: 3959
};

function toRad(x) {
  return x * Math.PI / 180;
};

// starting point: [<Float> longitude, <Float> latitude]
// ending point: [<Float> longitude, <Float> latitude]
// units: <Number> earth_radius
function haversineDistance(starting_point, end_point, units) {
  units || (units = 1);

  var lat1 = parseFloat(starting_point[1]),
      lat2 = parseFloat(end_point[1]);

  var lon1 = parseFloat(starting_point[0]),
      lon2 = parseFloat(end_point[0]);

  var dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1),
      dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);

  lat1 = toRad(lat1);
  lat2 = toRad(lat2);

  var arc = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  return (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(arc), Math.sqrt(1 - arc))) * units;
};

// LOS ANGELES, CA
var start = [-118.24, 33.97];

// SAN FRANCISCO, CA
var end   = [-122.41, 37.77];

var dist_kilometers = haversineDistance(start, end, earth_radius['kilometers']);
var dist_miles = haversineDistance(start, end, earth_radius['miles']);
```

Assuming you have made the result set from your SQL query as well as the users location available to the client side JavaScript, you could easily sort your locations by distance using the haversineDistance function inside of JavaScripts native array sort function.

```
var user_coords = [user_location.longitude, user_location.latitude];

sql_results.sort(function(a, b) {
  var a_coords = [a.longitude, a.latitude];
  var b_coords = [b.longitude, b.latitude];

  var a_dist = haversineDistance(user_coords, a_coords, earth_radius['miles']);
  var b_dist = haversineDistance(user_coords, b_coords, earth_radius['miles'])

  return a_dist - b_dist;
});
```

Comment: How can this script be used to deal with the question?

Comment: He could use the function I provided to sort his result set in JavaScript, as desired.

Comment: i am using SQLite from phonegap to be used for an iOS, android and blackberry app. does the result set come back as a array? and if so, then i guess i can use your sort function.